# how to "replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" using PowerShell for ACL folder access

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, filesystems, acl

I am trying to enable "replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" method using PowerShell, below is my Script

[image]

```
$ProfileDir = 'C:\Users\'
$Profiles = Get-ChildItem $ProfileDir \ Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($X in $Profiles) 
{
    $Profile = $ProfileDir + $X 
    Write-Host "Starting $Profile"

    $Acl = Get-Acl $Profile
    $Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $true)
    (Get-Item $Profile).SetAccessControl($Acl)

    $Permissions = (Get-Acl $Profile).Access | Where-Object 
    { 
        (-not $_.isInherited) -and $_.IdentityReference -like "domain\*"
    } 
    ForEach ($Y in $Permissions) 
    {
        $Acl.AddAccessRule($Y) 
    }
    
    (Get-Item $Profile).SetAccessRule($Acl)
    (Get-Acl $Profile).Access
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: `$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false)`?

Comment: I have tried that $Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $false) still not working

Comment: Can you share what is not working ? I don't understand why you try to re-add the not inherited ACLs for domain user inside the `$ACL` variable (which haven't been refreshed and I guess still contains the entries)

Comment: Hi, @Brice 
We have an application that needs to write some cache files in User Profile, Local Temp. The problem is, that the user profile folder has the full permissions but those are not inherited to all child objects due to it app not launching. 
When checking the box from GUI "replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object", the application is launched. 
This needs to apply to multiple users so I'm trying to put a script in GPO so that it will run when the user logs into the machine.

Comment: [`$profile` is an automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#profile) in powershell, you not attempt to assign a value to it as you're doing on your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Below is the script I have created and it worked as expected.
```

Thank you for your suggestions and help. To replace all child objects, I have used Get-ChildItem with -recurse and it worked.

```
$objName = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName.Split("\")[1]
$objDir = "C:\Users\$objName\"
$objUser = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
$objAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($objUser)
$objRule = $objUser,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow"
$objFileSec = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity
$objAccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objRule)
$objFileSec.SetOwner($objAccount)
$objAclSec = Get-Acl $objDir
$objAclSec.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
$objAclSec.PurgeAccessRules($objAccount)
$objAclSec.SetAccessRule($objAccessRule)
Get-ChildItem -Path $objDir | Set-Acl -AclObject $objAclSec
$objAclSec.Access | Format-Table
Pause
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  Migrating over final files during a laptop upgrade and I stumbled upon a stack of image files that all needed fixing like this.  I just needed to tweak my $objDir to the right file and that did the trick.