# Can I automate checking the "replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" with a script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, permissions, delete-file, removechild

First off I am aware there is software created for this but I am attempting to present this to an entrprise that is kind of strict on letting any old app into the environment. I have a Powershell script that does exactly what I need it to do... almost. I am attempting to remove user profile completely from a system but am failing at removing every last folder,subfolder, and file, as well as, the entire user folder itself.

This is the script that will remove any user of my choosing as well as exclude any user of my choosing. It works great! It removes the profile from settings, the key from regedit, and the user from "view advanced system settings"

```
$usersToDelete = "userb"
$excludedUserNames = "Administrator", "DefaultAccount", "Guest", "vboxuser"

foreach ($user in $usersToDelete) {
    Get-LocalUser $user | Remove-LocalUser
}

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath -match "^C:\\Users\\($([string]::Join('|', $usersToDelete)))$" -and $_.SID -notmatch "^S-1-5-18$" -and $_.SID -notmatch "^S-1-5-19$" -and $_.SID -notmatch "^S-1-5-20$" } | ForEach-Object {
    $sid = $_.SID
    $username = $_.LocalPath -replace "^C:\\Users\\"
    if ($username -notin $excludedUserNames) {
        Remove-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "SID='$sid'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $userPath = "C:\Users\$username"
        if (Test-Path $userPath) { Remove-Item $userPath -Recurse -Force }
        Remove-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$sid" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\$username" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        
        foreach ($user in $usersToDelete) {
            Get-LocalUser $user | Remove-LocalUser
        }
    
    }
    
}
$usersToDelete = "userb"

foreach ($user in $usersToDelete) {
    $userPath = "C:\Users\$user"
    if (Test-Path $userPath) {
        Remove-Item $userPath -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```

---

Unfortunately It gets held up at the folders in windows explorer. The main folder it gets held up on is "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Application Data"
I have found a fix that will allow me to run this script and delete the entire user folder.
Checking the "replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" Located by right click the USER that I want deleted folder -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced.
Once I check that box and re-run the script, the user is completely wiped from the PC as far as I can tell. Is there a way to automate this into a batch file or (even better) place it into my script? I would need the ability to do it for multiple users as well as the users of my choosing. Thank you!

These are a couple of batch files I have tried to grant myself permission but there is ALWAYS some file or folder that returns an "access denied" error.

```
set folder="C:\Users\userb\appdata"
takeown /F %folder% /R /D Y
icacls %folder% /reset /T
icacls %folder% /inheritance:r /grant:r "Authenticated Users":(OI)(CI)F /T
icacls %folder% /setowner "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /T
icacls %folder% /grant:r "SYSTEM":(OI)(CI)F /T
pause
```

---

```
set folder="C:\Users\userb\appdata"
takeown /F %folder% /R /D Y
icacls %folder% /reset /T
icacls %folder% /inheritance:r /grant:r "Authenticated Users":(OI)(CI)F /T
icacls %folder% /setowner "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /T
icacls %folder% /grant:r "SYSTEM":(OI)(CI)F /T
pause
```

---

And this is some of the solutions ChatGPT threw at me. None of which worked.

```
``$FolderPath = "C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Application Data"

# Get the folder object
$FolderACL = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath

# Enable inheritance for all child objects
$FolderACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($false, $true)

# Apply the changes to the folder
Set-Acl -Path $FolderPath -AclObject $FolderACL


Other script that may grant access
icacls C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local /grant USERNAME:(OI)(CI)F /T`
```

maybe this too\

```
`# Remove the user profile
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.SID -eq $UserSID } | ForEach-Object {
    $ProfilePath = $_.LocalPath
    Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $_
    Remove-Item -Path $ProfilePath -Recurse -Force
}
```

that is from this

```
# Specify the username whose profile you want to remove
`$Username = "UserA"`

# Get the SID of the user
`$UserSID = (Get-LocalUser -Name $Username).SID.Value`

# Remove the user profile
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.SID -eq $UserSID } | ForEach-Object {
    $ProfilePath = $_.LocalPath
    Remove-WmiObject -InputObject $_
    Remove-Item -Path $ProfilePath -Recurse -Force
}`

# Remove the user's registry key
`Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$UserSID" -Recurse -Force`

# Remove the user account
`Remove-LocalUser -Name $Username -Force``
```

---

```
$profilePath = "C:\Users\vboxuser"

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folder = $shell.NameSpace($profilePath)
$item = $folder.Self

$security = $item.GetAccessControl(1)
$securityDialog = $folder.ParentFolder.ParseName($item.Name).InvokeVerb("properties")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{SPACE}")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{DOWN}{TAB}{TAB}{SPACE}")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{SPACE}")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}{ENTER}")

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

$securityDialog.Close()
```

---

I also attempted this and it still did not work. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876626/how-to-replace-all-child-object-permission-entries-with-inheritable-permission`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876626/how-to-replace-all-child-object-permission-entries-with-inheritable-permission%60)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're most of the way there with the takeown and icacls, as you do indeed need to update the ownership and permissions first, as by default you won't have access. The following does the trick for me

```
Write-Output "`nTaking ownership of the folder"
TAKEOWN /F $userPath /A /R /D "Y" 1>$null

# Apply full access permissions for administrators with ICACLS
write-output "`nUpdating permissions"
ICACLS $userPath /grant Administrators:F /T 1>$null

Write-Output "`nDeleting user folder"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $userPath 2>&1
```

which is largely what you have above, but within the bit of code you have with TAKEOWN you're missing the /a switch which gives ownership to the Administrators group. Plus mine obviously doesn't bother trying to change the ownership side of things via ICACLS... but since I know this works on my setup I'd guess that may make a difference.

Also the slight difference in formatting/syntax between this and the code block above is because that's batchscript code, whereas this runs in my main Powershell code.

Comment: Dude.. You are the man. I did it. One script to completely eraticate the handpicked user profiles. Your script did the trick!! I edited it in the final script to start by taking full control of the files then at the end delete them all. I owe you a beer!!https://github.com/wywy1234/HandPicked-User-Profile-Removal-/blob/main/README.md

Comment: @WyattBlacker Awesome, glad that sorted it for you. Marking the answer as being the right answer (eg the tick on the left of it) will be thanks enough. ;)